# Why do invoking member function of GDI Plus kills the app?

Tags: c++

The program get killed as soon as I inoke `GetFamilyCount()` so the "Exit" is not printed.

Invoking `GetLastStatus()` prints value 18 which is equals to `GdiplusNotInitialized`

I'm not sure why it's not initialized. You can clearly see that I  initialized it here,

```
Gdiplus::PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection;
```

I'm using MinGW to build the program.

```
MinGW-w64 9.0.0
GCC Version 11.1
OS is Windows 10
```

MinGW taken from http://winlibs.com/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << "\n";

    Gdiplus::PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection; 

    std::cout << privateFontCollection.GetLastStatus() << "\n";

    std::cout << privateFontCollection.GetFamilyCount() << "\n";

    std::cout << "Exit" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The error means you haven't called [`GdiplusStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Wow, I haven't found that one before. Thanks, It works!

Comment: @jeffbRTC You should [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start), for instance the doc for the [Status enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplustypes/ne-gdiplustypes-status) says: "*`GdiplusNotInitialized` Indicates that the GDI+API is not in an initialized state. To function, all GDI+ objects require that GDI+ be in an initialized state. **Initialize GDI+ by calling [GdiplusStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup)**.*"